# Install WAS 7.0 on RHEL 6

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel6, websphere

I am trying to install Websphere 7 x64 on RHEL 6 x64.

I am using Developer edition.

When I try to execute `./install` on the command prompt, it waits for few seconds and then returns to prompt without any error.

I have installed all the pre-requisites as listed in this article:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftins_linuxsetup_rhel6.html

Any idea how to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: command line, silent or graphical installation?  I believe the default installation is graphical.

Comment: Yes, graphical ...

Comment: and do you have a graphical environment set up or are you using X forwarding?  Does xclock or any other graphical tool work?  Is there anything in the logs listed in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tins_trouble.html

The following logs may be helpful:
Browse the relevant log files for clues:

- The main installation log file: app_server_root/logs/log.txt.
- The profile creation log for creating the profile: app_server_root/logs/manageprofiles/profile_name_create.log.
- IBM® HTTP Server log:

  - IHS_root/logs/install/log.txt if the installation completed
  - user_temp/ihslogs/log.txt if the installation was interrupted, or user_temp/ihslogs/log_date_stamp.time_stamp.txt if installation finishes but is unsuccessful or for some other reason cannot be copied to IHS_root/logs/install/log.txt
- The log files produced when the default application .ear file is installed are: app_server_root/profiles/profile_name/logs/defaultapp_config.log and app_server_root/profiles/profile_name/logs/defaultapp_deploy.log.
- Other logs for other applications for a profile in the app_server_root/profiles/profile_name/logs directory.